# How to get notified when a child process exits and closes a pipe?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048560/how-to-fork-and-exec-a-server-and-wait-until-its-ready):

Suppose I have a Python program, which forks and execs another Python program with `subprocess.Popen`.

I would like to create a pipe before the fork and get notification when the child closes the pipe when it exits. I don't want to wait for the pipe synchronously, of course. Is it doable in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use subprocess `poll()`
Although you will have to test every now and then to see if it has finished

Calling program:

```
import subprocess
import time
c=subprocess.Popen(['python', 'called.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
finished = False
while finished == False:
    if c.poll() != None:
        finished = True
        break
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Still working"
print "finished"
```

Called program:

```
import time
time.sleep(15)
```